# Spark Streaming Job Becomes Slow After Prolonged Activity: Understanding Output Duration and Potential Causes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm having a problem with a Spark engine I built, and I'd like to understand a specific behavior. There's a legacy Spark streaming engine that starts to slow down after being active for some time.

Some time ago, I had a similar problem that was caused by incorrect use of caches. After adjusting the processes, the engines stopped slowing down, with the exception of one.

The strange behavior is that the output op duration is much longer than the job execution time.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what might cause this, besides the incorrect use of cache? What defines the output op duration?